# Android Firebase fetching data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now I read the Firebase documentation for android. I saw all the events onDataChange etc. But I didn't get 1 thing. Let's say I want to initialize my activity with some information from the database. No data has changed, no nothing. So it seems this event onDataChange won't help me. How can I explicitly say something like "go and fetch the data from firebase".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a `ValueEventListener`, its `onDataChange` method is called "immediately" with a snapshot of the current data.

If you attach the listener with `addValueEventListener` it will (in addition) be called upon any subsequent change to the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that when the activity is initialized, so is a data structure with info from the database.

Retrieving data is pretty explicit here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Also, you should be really careful because you should be using callbacks. If the activity needs to populate its views depending on that data, you should be aware of having that data before creating the views or trying to instantiate with null objects.

Comment: this is the "admin" section (the link, PS: no idea what is that Admin section lol) not the android https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write this is the android page

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data only once, see:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once

You "use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method to simplify this scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again."